# In CoreData, how should I call context.save()?

Tags: swift, core-data

In CoreData, what is the best approach for using context.save()? Should I call it when the object is added in the array or should I add all the objects together in the array and then call context.save()?

It is kind of confusing because I did not get accurate answer.

I have tried both I do not know what should be the proper approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I have understood reading your question is that the best approach in my opinion is to call `context.save()` once because calling it frequently can cause issues. Therefore, my suggestion is to add all the data in your array and then call `context.save()`. I hope this clears your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The latter.

If multiple objects are added in a loop, save the context once after the loop.